# In Ruby, what does "new" mean in {1 => new("alice")}?

Tags: ruby, class

I'm new in Ruby and I mat the following code today. I've searched the "Ruby programming language" book but did not find explanation to this syntax. Could someone help to explain? I know to create an object you need to use something like `Person.new("My name")`.

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize name
    @name = name
  end

  def self.find id
    people = {1 => new("alice"), 2 => new("bob")}
    people[id]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` is a class method.

In a class method, `self` refers the class. In a method, `self` can be omitted.

So, `new` means `self.new`; which is equivalent to `Person.new` in this case.